# Flow Builder OR logic on required fields in same screen?

Tags: visual-workflow, required-field

I have a simple flow screen where I want a user to EITHER select a contact from a radio button record choice set, OR create a new contact by filling in  a name, email, and phone screen component.

I can't figure out how to make this an OR requirement - e.g. they either need to do one or the other but they shouldn't do both and it is mandatory.  Also, it looks like the Name component doesn't even have a required attribute.  What's the best way to achieve this functionality?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

### Conditional Visibility

You could have a radio button group to control the visibility of the other input components (by setting up [conditional visibility](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_ref_elements_screen_conditional_visibility.htm&type=5) on them). The options for this radio group would be:

- Create New Contact
- Select Existing Contact

You could select one option by default to minimise the number of clicks for users.

### Making Name Required

You're correct in that it doesn't look like the [**Name** input component](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_ref_elements_screencmp_name.htm&type=5) can be made required.

Instead, you could use multiple [**Text** input components](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_ref_elements_screencmp_text.htm&type=5) to capture the name - each of those could be made required.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Question though.  I would still have to make all of these fields required to make sure the contact selection or new contact fields were filled in.  If one choice was hidden but still required, wouldn't it prevent user from progressing in the flow?

Comment: Good question, no. "Screen input components hidden by conditional visibility are not required when a user runs the flow, even if Required is set to {!$GlobalConstant.True}. Once the component appears to the user, it is treated as required.": https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_considerations_design_conditional_visibility.htm&type=5

Comment: Awesome, I got it working.  Thank you.  I should note that the component visibility seems fairly buggy.  It didn't work / evaluate correctly when I used true as the record choice value and it doesn't work when you evaluate the actual record choice.  I had to evaluate the radio button screen component and use "new" and "existing" for the record choice values.